# JQuery UI : Drag and Drop : Deal with several containers and overflow property

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am completely stuck on a drag and drop problem: I need to be able to drag the yellow squares located in the cells of the row 1 into one of the cells of the row 3.

I made a small JS Bin example [here](http://jsbin.com/upunek/16/edit)

My constraints are that all the cells must have the property "overflow" because the cells can have plenty of yellow squares.

I tried to apply the property "clone / original" and "AppendTo" to the draggable elements, but I didn't manage to deal with the main container scrollbar which have the property overflow as well.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Up, I am really stuck. Maybe it is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For being able to drag the element to another table cell, you need to set the "helper" option to "clone".

```
$(this).draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false
});
```

Now in the "drop" event of the droppable, `ui.draggable` is the element that is being dragged. What you need to do it to append it the droppable.

```
$(this).droppable({
    ...
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("cell-dropped");
        // "ui.draggable" is the element being dragged
        // "this" is the droppable element
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

For the scrolling of the container DIV, you have to explicitly set it's css position value to relative:

```
.container{
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/QvRjL/)**

Comment: Hi Didier, thank you very much for your answer and for the time that you spent on my problem. Unfortunately, I am still not able to drag my yellow boxes from the row 1 to the row 3 and more in your demo because the main container has the overflow property and the 'clone' option doesn't permit (not sure, in fact I hope not...) to scroll-down

Comment: I missed that part indeed. I will see if I can come up with something :-)

Comment: Found out what the problem was. I've updated the fiddle and the answer.